# Capacitive reactance

Tags: capacitance, reactance

I'm doing AC theory as an electrical apprentice now, and my lecturer said that inductive reactance and capacitive reactance both work with Faraday's law, or back-EMF, is this correct for capacitive reactance as well?

Comment: No, "Faraday's Law" is "Faraday's Law of Induction".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_law_of_induction

Answer (score 1):

Faraday's Law deals with induced EMF in a conductor (inductive elements) when exposed to a changing magnetic field. When the term back EMF is used, it implies a conductor rotating in a magnetic field, such as in a motor.

Capacitive elements are not part of Faraday's Law.

The statement by the lecturer about back EMF does imply a motor. In single phase AC motors, a capacitor is  used in conjunction with a start winding to generate a torque in the motor in a specific direction so the motor starts rotating in the desired direction.

Maybe the lecturer wasn't clear on how the capacitor works in a motor, or its function in the motor.

Comment: We were talking about just simple reactance, and only just started our ac theory block, the lecturer stated that both capacitive and inductive reactance 'are the back emf created by the capacitive and inductive elements when voltage is applied'. Which didn't seem right to me at all

Answer (score 0):

> The lecturer stated that both capacitive and inductive reactance 'are
>   the back emf created by the capacitive and inductive elements when
>   voltage is applied'

Either the lecturer is wrong or you misheard/misinterpreted the lecturer.

Comment: He said he was unsure about it all, he hadn't taufht it in a while but It didn't seem right to me so I thought I'd make sure, thanks!

Comment: @DanielSmith When in doubt, always go back to the basic formula: V = L di/dt and I = C dV/dt. To get a big voltage across an inductor try forcing a high rate of change of current through it and to get a big current thru a cap force a high rate of change of voltage across it. Shorting a cap that has a voltage on its terminals produces a very large current and open circuiting an inductor while current is flowing produces a very large voltage.

Comment: Ah awesome, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When the capacitor is charged in an AC circuit it discharges back into the circuit at zero crossing.  So it does generate a counter voltage.  They don't call it Back EMF but rather counter voltage.

It is illustrated in Electricity 1-7 on page 4-21 Harry 
Mileaf revised second edition.

Comment: A reference that people can view online would be much better than a book reference. Can you provide a link?